# Is there an Annotation for method, to work as a trigger in Java Spring?

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I would like to execute certain method every time a specific Entity is persisted. This method should perform some kind of checking on entity object, so its need a access to this specific object.

Is there an Annotation, or other method allowing me to do so? Basically, it should be working like some kind of trigger.

Comment: Can't you call it on construction?

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, my mistake. I meant when entity is persisted (I've already edited my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events

So you can use `@PostPersist` inside your entity

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using entity validation annotations directly on your entity objects, e.g. hibernate entity annotations. If you register your entity validator, these can be called automatically prior to entity save.

Answer (score 0):

does `after` point cut of spring aop can solve your problem?